# Samhain: depth of "-1"

Tags: linux, security, unix

In a samhainrc file you are allowed to have a depth associated with your dir. Like so:

```
dir=3/etc/tinydns
```

But what does it mean when you have a depth of -1? ( I was not able to find anything in the man page regarding particular numbers for depth.)

Comment: Personally I prefer The Misfits to Samhain or Danzig. London Dungeon is a killer... Kidding of course.

Comment: I had to +1 that for the memories of my youth.

Comment: LOL... a little bit of silliness

Comment: Less Silliness than Shallowness, I think!  (Sorry; couldn't help myself...)

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found out the answer to my own question. Apparently I didn't use Google right the first time. So the answer if anyone is looking that you use a "-1", if you want to exclude a subdirectory.

FAQ: 3.1. How can I exclude a (sub-)directory ?
http://www.la-samhna.de/samhain/FAQ.html#File%20checking0